# How to force PyCharm to evaluate tensorflow.contrib LazyLoader so it auto-completes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, autocomplete, pycharm

Python novice here...

If I only import TensorFlow's root package, auto-complete doesn't seem to work for `tf.contrib` due to that module being loaded through `LazyLoader`:

[image]

However, if I import `tensorflow.contrib.learn`, then PyCharm knows how to auto-complete it from there:

[image]

How can I only `import tensorflow as tf` and have PyCharm know how to auto-complete its properties without me having to import each thing individually?

I'm using PyCharm 2017.2.3 (Community Edition)

Comment: I am not a PyCharm user, but on my side, on VsCode, by configuring the 'Language Server' and setting it to 'Pylance' allows me to get proper intellisence.

Check how to configure language server in a PyCharm context.